# strange behaviour on C# culture decimal to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, asp.net-mvc-2

preco is a money field on database, im using ASP.MVC 2

cutureinfo is pt-BR

```
oc.preco 11.11 decimal
oc.preco.ToString() "11,1100" string
```

idk why this strange behaviuor

Comment: What behaviour do you expect ?

Comment: the cultureinfo set 2 decimal, so why "11,1100" ? if i set in debug time the oc.preco manually itoString wotks fine.

Comment: Did you use the Entity Framework? I think EF converts money to a decimal in the form of x.1234.

Comment: Nope, i fill the Entity with return of a procedure.

Comment: What's the type of field preco in C# ?

Comment: preco is a decimal type.

Comment: Roger get te problem, really decimal has 4 digits, i need to truncate, but de Debug windows is only showing 2 digits

Comment: Could you reproduce this error without database and mvc ? Just in plain console app or in unit test ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming **preco** is **string** you have problem in conversion in database, because this code works well:

```
var d = (decimal)11.11;
var ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR");
Console.Write(d.ToString(ci));
```

It gives "11,11"